New issues installing packages with ansible, packer and aws
We have a system whereby we packup some code, build a web server and bundle that all into an AMI, ready to be served on AWS.
It was all working fine until I updated both ansible and packer, we also updated the packer.json file to the new hcl format using the built in convert command.
amazon-ebs.autogenerated_1: fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "No package matching 'build-essential' is available"}

ansible core 2.13.13
Packer v1.10.2

We are using this image as a base for the server.
filters = {
    name                = "ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-*"
    root-device-type    = "ebs"
    virtualization-type = "hvm"
  }

Now when ansible starts installing some packages we need, it seems to have an issue with the packages:

build-essential
supervisor

in particular.
We have tried different ways of doing apt-get update, both using the "shell" ansible command and the regular "apt" command, with a variation of cache updates etc.
The strange thing is, the more garbage we can print to the screen (using for example --verbose when executing the ansible playbook), or by using "cat" on a file, for example I just cat'd /etc/apt/sources.list before the task to install the packages, the further along to process we get. This leads me to believe that there might be a race condition somewhere, but I cannot for the life of me figure out why.
Here is the command we are using to install packages.
- name: Install common dependencies
  apt:
    name:
      - htop
      - nano
      - wget
      - perl
      - unzip
      - tcpdump
      - build-essential
      - python3-distutils
      - libwww-perl
      - supervisor
      - mysql-client
    state: present

Like I mentioned before, this worked flawlessly until updating ansible and packer.

We had a similar issue, and after a lot of digging I isolated the issue with the upgrade of packer-plugin-amazon from 1.3.1 to 1.3.2. So, what I did was to exclude that version from the Packer configuration, at least for now:
packer {
  required_plugins {
    amazon = {
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/amazon"
      version = "~> 1, != 1.3.2"  # v1.3.2 has apt issues
    }
    ansible = {
      source  = "github.com/hashicorp/ansible"
      version = "~> 1"
    }
  }
}


Could you refer link or document regarding apt issues on v1.3.2? This will be helpful for users to read

Sorry for the delay in replying! This wasn't the exact way that we managed to fix the issue, but it was a version issue :)
